# Add confirm (Yes /No) dialog box inside Model class in Adempiere

Tags: java, swing, model, adempiere

I want to create confirm dialog box inside Model class.
I created window which has several text boxes and after entering the values user can save data. At the point of saving data I want to add a confirm dialog box asking "Are you sure to save these data ?"
So inside Model class I tried to put

```
org.adempiere.webui.window.FDialog.ask(1,null,"Are you sure to save these data ?");
```

When I add this into my code, it will give errors and I can't build the project.

If anyone knows how to add confirm dialog box in model class? Please help me to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adempiere
For Swing Class (i.e.) model class you can use by below

```
 int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, Are you sure to save these data ?
                            "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
 if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
   ;                    
 else
   ;
```

or 
Adialog in Client modules cann't used in Base modules

```
ADialog.ask(WindowNo, null,"Are you sure to save these data ?");
```

FDialog Should be used only in ZKWebui package, never use zk classes in base/client modules

```
org.adempiere.webui.window.FDialog.ask(1,null,"Are you sure to save these data ?")
```

In window/tab before save you can use "**Commit Warning**" column in Window,Tab & field (Application Dictionary)

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @Selvi Thanks selvi... But still I can't use JOptionPane in base/src/org/compiere/model. When I use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog system get stuck.. So is there any option ?

Comment: Im sure JOptionPane will works i used in base/src/org/compiere/Callout, Could you post the code in which class/method or whats specification?

Comment: this is my code....                                               int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, warningMsg,msgTitle,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
   if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){    show msg();}

Comment: In window/tab  before save you can use "Commit Warning" column  in Tab &field (Application Dictionary) im not sure with aftersave

Comment: @selvi, How it will work web version ? Does ZK can understand the JOPtionPane?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JOptionPane` but not ADialog or FDialog.
Usage of ADialog throws build error. As its is defined in client folder, you cant use it in the upper hierarchy.

You can find the build order from [here](http://tekadempiere.blogspot.in/2014/01/cleanup-of-ant-build-scripts.html)

Comment: Thanks Saj.... But still I can't use JOptionPane in base/src/org/compiere/model . Is there any option?

Comment: ADempiere have its own standard on its message boxes. I wont prefer to use JOptionpane. 
What is your actual problem? 
1. Pop up message issue?
2. Build issue ?

Comment: @Saj :- It would be pop-up message issue in web version.